# Can't work out theright keyboard type and layout for new keyboard

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I recently bought a [keychron C1](https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-c1-wired-mechanical-keyboard?variant=32321246888025) keyboard. I can't get all the keys to do what they say they should do on them.

For example:

- the current ` and ~ key and shift produces ¬ instead of ~
- the | and \ key produces # and with shift ~

This means currently I don't have a way of using pipe or backslash so have to reach over to my laptop keyboard.

How do I work out what settings to change in the keyboard settings?

I'm using xubuntu 21.04

Comment: It seems to be an Apple compatible keyboard judging by the photos. I would be looking at US layouts with "Macintosh" variants.

Comment: I've changed it to that, but it seems no different @ChanganAuto . Do I need to reboot after changing it?

Comment: A reboot isn't needed, usually.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the keyboard layout is US ANSI. Open Terminal `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` select General 104 > US, this should do. If not you must complain the company that your keyboard has some keys misallocated.

Comment: It seems that neither changing the keyboard layout through the gui or via dpkg are actually having an effect (on either my external keychron keyboard or my laptop one). For example if I change it to dvorak it still types as qwerty.

Comment: Ok, rebooting after using dpkg seems to have fixed it. As far as I can tell using the gui did nothing.